# Creating a user defined function that applies an equation to each row

Tags: r, rows, custom-function

I'm trying to build a function that will apply an equation to each row of a variable and paste the output in another column of a data frame. It's the first bit of my first attempt to build a function and I'm totally stuck. The function creates a couple of columns and then should apply the equation to the columns. So far I've got:

```
cpeat <- function(data, mo, ko) { 
  data$t1 <- data$t
  data$t2 <- lead(data$t1)
  data$al <- ((mo/ko)*log((1+ko*t2)/(1+ko*t1)))
data.frame("t1" = data$t1, 
           "t2" = data$t2,
           "annual_layer" = data$al)
}
```

Testing the code returns what I need, but the equation (data$al column) is only applied to the top row and pasted down the column.

I've searched pretty hard and it seems I could just create a function that is solely the equation, and use apply, but this is just the start of what will likely be a end up being a complex function, so I need the columns created properly.

Any help would be massively appreciated,
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to write a function, you are already using dplyr why not use it fully?

```r
# df is the data.frame you had
# you have to set mo and ko in the global environment ie mo=.9; ko=0.7
df %>% mutate(t1=t, t2=lead(t), annual_layer=(mo/ko)*log((1+ko*t2)/(1+ko*t1)))
```

## Edit

```r
cpeat <- function(data, mo, ko) {
     if(!require(dplyr)){
          install.packages("dplyr")
          library(dplyr)
     }
     data %>% mutate(t1=t, t2=lead(t), annual_layer=(mo/ko)*log((1+ko*t2)/(1+ko*t1))) %>% select(-t)
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your answer, it gives me what I need. But I wanted a function as I'm going to have to apply this a lot of times, and share it with people who don't really use r. So i thought a function which could do all this and the other bits i need would be a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: Either check the return value of `require` (and do something if `FALSE`) or use `library`. Using `require` in this fashion is otherwise fragile.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I suggest writing a function that works on *vectors* and returns a *vector*, as it can be applied in just about any other usage and within grouping if needed without modification. In this example (untested):

```r
cpeat <- function(t1, mo, ko) (mo/ko)*log((1+ko*lead(t1))/(1+ko*t1))
data$annual_layer <- cpeat(data$t, data$mo, data$ko)
```

This is general enough that it'll work transparently in just about any situation (base, tidyverse, `data.table`).

If you need it to return all three columns for some reference, then you can use something similar to what you already had, but still using vectors:

```r
cpeat <- function(t1, mo, ko) {
  t2 <- lead(t1)
  data.frame(
    t1 = t1, t2 = t2,
    out = (mo/ko)*log((1+ko*t2)/(1+ko*t1))
  )
}
```

And this can be used in base R, tidyverse, ... rather directly:

```r
# base R
cbind(dat, with(dat, cpeat(t, mo, ko)))
# tidyverse
dat %>%
  bind_cols(cpeat(.$t, .$mo, .$ko))
```

Note: this can run into problems (e.g., having names pre-assigned) if this is done when any of the names already exist.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just use the `apply` function, so it would look like:

`apply(data, 1, cpeat(data, mo, ko))`?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/apply

Comment: `cpeat` does not return a function, so this is incorrect usage of `apply`.

Comment: AH, so sorry about that :(